# ggsave() is shrinking the text size of plot when saved

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(tidyverse)

economics %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, unemploy)) +
  geom_point()

ggsave("temp.jpg")
```

When trying to save a plot via `ggsave()`, it looks fine in the plot viewer on macOS however when saved it shrinks the title, caption, and axis labels. I've tried adjusting the DPI, axis and title sizes, and width/height and a fresh install of all packages however all plots are being shrunk down.

[image: Normal Plot]

[image: Shrunk plot]

Comment: Have you tried using extreme values e.g. `ggsave("temp.jpg", width = 1, height = 1)` to see the effect?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. I get normal text size.

Comment: @benson23 yes, and it will still shrink the text, and captions etc.

Comment: Text size isn't relative; it's absolute. Either the resolution, the plot size, or the scale changes between your first and second plot. [Check it out.](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/08/taking-control-of-plot-scaling/)

Comment: Please show the exact code you are using for a couple different sizes and the results. For example `ggsave("temp_72.jpg", width = 7, height = 5, dpi = 72)` and `ggsave("temp_300.jpg", width = 7, height = 5, dpi = 300)`, and `ggsave("temp_small_72.jpg", width = 4, height = 3, dpi = 72)`

Comment: If you add backticks? Or did part of your comment go missing? If you were marking it as code inline, you can use one backtick on each side. (If you weren't aware.)